# How do i get the number of types of letters in a string? (Python)

Tags: python, string, counting

im making a script in python, and i want to know how to count the **types of letters** in a string. For example, if my string is `abcc`, it should return 3. because theres a, b, and c. if its `accc`, it should return 2. if its `abcdeff` it should return 6. So, how do i do this?

Comment: So, `len(set(str))`?

Comment: At least make an *effort* to do your own homework. What good is that degree you didn't earn if you don't know enough to keep the job it gets you?